# PHP odbc_connect Foxpro database

Tags: php, foxpro

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to actually connect to a FoxPro database or free table via php `odbc_connect`. I've tried other examples but it doesn't want to connect.

If I'm using odbc_connect what will I need to put in the quotes?

`$conn = odbc_connect ('','','');`

There is no password to the FoxPro database or user associated with the table. What would be the value of the `$dsn` variable?

Comment: set up a DSN for the foxpro db, then just use that DSN in the connect calls.

Answer (score 1):

This page shows appropriate ODBC connection strings for VFP, both database and free tables: https://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro/